# How to implement the Business Logic layer and the Repository Layer with Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, data-access-layer, business-logic

I am trying to create the Business Logic (Service) and the Repository (Data access) Layer for my application. I want to do it correctly but I am not an expert.

For the moment, for the Repository layer, I've created an interface **IMainDao** that extends **JpaRepository**:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface IMainDao extends JpaRepository<Object, Integer>{
}
```

So all my repositories interfaces can extend the IMainDao:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface IUserDao extends IMainDao{

}
```

I also created the Business Logic layer. An interface **IMainService**:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface IMainService {

    Object getById(int id);
    List<Object> getAll();
    Object create(Object o);
    Object update(Object o);
    void delete(int id);
}
```

The implementation of this interface **MainService**

```
@Service
public class MainService implements IMainService{

    @Autowired
    private IMainDao mainDao;

    @Override
    public Object getById(int id) {
        return mainDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> getAll() {
        return mainDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Object create(Object o) {       
        Object obj = mainDao.save(o);     
        return obj;
    }

//Other methods...
```

And the other interfaces like **IUserService** that extend **IMainService**:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface IUserService extends IMainService{

}
```

With their implementations:

```
public abstract class UserService implements IUserService{

}
```

Am I doing it correctly? If no, what do you recommend to me and where can I optimize?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to create my other interface without having to recreate the methods in their implementations.

Comment: Ok first spring doesn’t work this way. JpaRepository needs to know what entity type it’s dealing with, putting in Object doesn’t work. You can’t auto wire by type if everything you inject has the same type.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I deleted the IMainDao so all my Repositories extend JpaRepository. But, regarding the Services, I want to avoid recreating the methods like `public Object getById(int id) { return mainDao.findById(id); }` in their implementations

Comment: @Johna said IMainDao is unnecessary. You can directly extend you repositories from JpaRepository.
And service classes are where you put your business logic. What you are actually doing is writing a business logic in the service classes and provide adapters to access those for repositories so your adapters are Repository interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Your `IMainDao` seems unnecessary. You can define interfaces as needed for the entities like: `User, Order`

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}

@Repository
interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {}
```

And, in your business logic layer you can have service interfaces and their implementations like:

```
@Service
interface UserService{
    ... method declarations goes here
} 

class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository;     

   ... implement interface methods 
}
```

If you have common methods in multiple service classes you can have a generic service interface, otherwise, `IMainService` has no meaning.

==== [EDIT] INTRODUCING GENERIC SERVICE INTERFACE ====

Let's imagine both `UserService` and `OrderService` have common search methods. Then we can have a generic service interface (`SearchService`) and implement it in required service implementation classes.

```
interface SearchService<T, I> {
  T findLatestOne(){}
  T lastEditedOne(){}
  List<T> searchByKeywords{}    
}

class UserService implements SerchService<User, Long> {
  User findLatestOne(){ ... implementation }
  User lastEditedOne(){ ... implementation }
  List<User> searchByKeywords{ ... implementation }
}

class OrderService implements SerchService<Order, Long> {
  Order findLatestOne(){ ... implementation }
  Order lastEditedOne(){ ... implementation }
  List<Order> searchByKeywords{ ... implementation }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I deleted the IMainDao so all my Repositories extend JpaRepository. What do you mean by generic service interface. Can you show me an example ?

Comment: Please check the edited section for an example of how to have a generic service interface in business logic layer.

Comment: I've read some tutorials and your right, the best way is with generic classes. But, in your example, I have to implement each method for all the Services and these methods do the same job. I want a class that implements `SearchService` so the Services can extend it. The problem is that, I don't have a generic DAO that I can use in this class. Thanks!

Comment: If you see search methods are similar across business logic classes, you can make the `SerachService` an abstract class and extend it in relevant classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to define repositories as needed for your entity model.

```
@Repository
public interface IUserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

The API of the implementation will be adjusted to the generics defined.

Regarding the Services, follow that approach; develop toward interfaces and implement them to provide the concrete functionality, relying on the injected repositories. Although, try to avoid inheritance in services; most of the times this is not really needed, unless something really specific warrants it, like common logic that, through generics, should be adjusted to the specifics of the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand about the repositories. In my Services, I want to avoid recreating the methods like `public Object getById(int id) {
        return mainDao.findById(id);
    }` in their implementations. How can I do?

Comment: I think that you would have to sacrifice the design of your entity model to achieve something like that. It's a little extra effort that will serve well your design and make your code more understandable